# Implementing Nuget in our corporate environment - how to have it work with our AD accounts instead of normal usernames/passwords?

Tags: c#-4.0, nuget, nugetgallery

I've been fighting this for a while, but how would we get our internal implementation of Nuget to work with our AD accounts instead of a normal registration process that requires a unique username and password?  For example, in our corporate environment, here's the screen I get.  Notice that the app **does** in fact see my AD account, but it's asking me to log in (blurred out the domain/username for security purposes):

[image]

Comment: Our product [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) comes with this feature in the paid enterprise edition, if that interests you.

Comment: At MikeM : Not having to deal with AzMan would probably make ProGet worth it.  I do not have any affiliation with ProGet, fyi.  I just hate AzMan.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is promising:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/p3net/archive/2013/03/30/nuget-with-active-directory-support.aspx